# Changing elements of a tibble within a function

Tags: r

I have a set of string variables in my tibble that I want to recode into specific integers based on the content of their strings.  My code looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

a<-c("this string says apple", "this string says banana", "this string says carrot", "this string says apple")
b<- c("this string says pumpkin", "this string says radish", "this string says eggplant", "this string says radish")
produce <- tibble(a,b)

a_words <- c("apple", "banana", "carrot")
b_words <- c("pumpkin", "radish", "eggplant")

my_function<-function(var,word_vec,num_vec){ 
  for (i in seq_along(word_vec)){
    var[grepl(word_vec[[i]],var)]<-num_vec[[i]]
  }
  return(var)
}
```

I am able to get the desired result when I process each variable separately:

```
produce$a <- my_function(produce$a,a_words,1:3)
produce$b <- my_function(produce$b,b_words,1:3)

> produce
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  a     b    
  <chr> <chr>
1 1     1    
2 2     2    
3 3     3    
4 1     2
```

But in reality I have several variables to recode (but not all the variables in the tibble).  I have tried a loop function:

```
for (i in c("produce$a", "produce$b")){
  i <- my_function(i, paste0(str_replace(i,"produce$", ""),"_words"), 1:3)
}
```

But this makes no changes to the produce tibble.

Any suggestions on how to do this more efficiently would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
words <- list(
    a = c("apple", "banana", "carrot"),
    b = c("pumpkin", "radish", "eggplant"))

produce %>%
    rowid_to_column("row") %>%
    gather(key, val, -row) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(val = map_int(words[key], ~which(str_detect(val, .x) == TRUE))) %>%
    spread(key, val) %>%
    select(-row)
## A tibble: 4 x 2
#      a     b
#  <int> <int>
#1     1     1
#2     2     2
#3     3     3
#4     1     2
```

The key here is to

- store `words` in a `list` with names matching the column names in `produce`,
- convert `produce` from wide to long, and
- regexp-match entries from columns with names in `key` with the matching entries from `words` before re-shaping data back from long to wide.

Answer (score 0):

You've done a good job but you've made a few confusions.

First of all, you made one regarding the difference between strings and variables "produce$a" is not the same as produce$a. The function `get()` is what you need to get the 2nd one from the first one.

Also, the function `paste0()` is making some evaluation on some symbols of the string you're passing as its argument. "$" is one of them.

To finish, you have to learn to use different accessor to the columns of your data frame other than *df$X*, for exemple *df[["X"]]* or *df["X"]*. They have their own way of behaving, you should learn about that.

Anyway, below is the code that - I think - you were looking for.

```
for (i in c("a", "b")){
  print(my_function(produce[[i]], get(paste0(i,"_words")), 1:3))
}
```

*NB: I changed the list of the loop to c("a", "b") because it's easier to understand but you could have also looped over `c("produce$a", "produce$b")` and get the solution with a few changed.*

Comment: This worked!  Thank you.  Can you suggest documentation for where to use df$X vs. df[X] vs. df[[X]]?

Comment: The best book for R by the best R developer in R : advanced R by Hadley Wickham (and it’s free!) http://adv-r.had.co.nz/